# What is this animated French short film that looked like a Disney film with a little touch of anime?

Tags: story-identification, anime, disney, animation, short-film

- It is about a couple like Romeo and Juliet being chased by robots and/or similar to "Mars Express" and/or "Fantastic Planet" (I think).
- Cyberpunk and/or Steampunk sort of.
- I saw it on Youtube a few years ago, and someone said in the comments section that "It kind of looked like an anime." Something like that.
- Not "Radiant" or "Wakfu." From the parts I saw, I know that these two are not it.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SF&F. You have some good info here, but could you also have a look at [this list](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/39144) and [edit] in any more information you can remember?

Comment: In case of doubt. The animation short that I watched is similar to this: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VG0bJHwUR0I Am I that wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Might it be **April and the Extraordinary World**?

It’s French, animation, steampunk, and features a young heroine and hero on the run, but it’s feature length.